# Could I get a Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange historic timeline?

Tags: feature-request

I would like to have a way to see my history on Stack Overflow.

- Questions (added / voted / favourite / edited / reviewed)
- Answers (added / voted / edited / reviewed)
- Comments
- Badges

Something like a SO timeline perhaps? Or maybe even a Stack Exchange wide timeline?

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/users/201482/kees-c-bakker?tab=activity or even this http://stackexchange.com/users/69191/kees-c-bakker?tab=activity

Comment: @hims056 its cool i did not know tha t

Comment: Wow... didn't now that :) supers :). Can you add it as answer for future reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already see all your activity on the "Activity" tab within your profile.

> [image]

For example, your Stack Overflow activity can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201482/kees-c-bakker?tab=activity). And your Stack Exchange profile has a similar tab for your global activity.

> [image]

In your case it's [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/69191/kees-c-bakker?tab=activity).